some python modules cannot be recognized by pylance in vscode
I have installed a python module from source with the following command
cd /path/to/ligpargen
pip install -e . --config-settings editable_mode=strict

According to this it should be the right way to make pylance to find editable module. But it turns out not work at all.
I am sure that I am using the right virtual environment and I can import the module in the interactive mode. And I also check the lib python where the module is installed. As you can find in the screenshot,there is a LigPargen-2.1.dist-info, but there is no a module named ligparagen like the others.  I have no idea how to fix this.


you can try to find LigParGen in a virtual environment by commanding python -m pip show ligpargen. If not, you try to install it in that environment. Then use the shortcut keys Ctrl+Shift+P to enter the control panel. Input the Select Interpreter selection, and note that the selected Python environment is the same as LigPargen.

According to this, either strict or compat mode will work.
In my case compat mode do solve the problem but I have no idea why it works.

It's great to hear that you've found a good solution to your problem. This may be because the compatibility mode uses PLS as its backend. In this case, some missing information can be solved.
